# Custom Pagination on Laravel With Bootsrap 5

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-5

i need to custom my pagination on mobile view, in default bootsrap 5 on laravel,  the pagination only show prev and next button,
[default bootsrap 5 pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTw4v.png)
i need to custom to be prev 1 2 3 next

any solution?

my expectation pagination in mobile views
[Expectiation Pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pJFK.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please find this link for more details on how to customize the default pagination:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

so in this you need to publish the default pagination files and modify the pagination file as per your need and file location is resources/views/vendor/pagination/bootstrap-5.blade.php.
1.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-fill d-none">
```

instead of

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-fill d-sm-none">
```

2. 

```
<div class="flex-sm-fill d-sm-flex align-items-sm-center justify-content-sm-between d-flex">
```

instead of

```
<div class="d-none flex-sm-fill d-sm-flex align-items-sm-center justify-content-sm-between">
```

Result: https://prnt.sc/Pvyk2c_VIt5A

If you want to remove the showing no of records block then please remove below lines:

```
<div>
            <p class="small text-muted">
                {!! __('Showing') !!}
                <span class="fw-semibold">{{ $paginator->firstItem() }}</span>
                {!! __('to') !!}
                <span class="fw-semibold">{{ $paginator->lastItem() }}</span>
                {!! __('of') !!}
                <span class="fw-semibold">{{ $paginator->total() }}</span>
                {!! __('results') !!}
            </p>
        </div>
```

Result: https://prnt.sc/dDWz2h9A-_XK